# Calling methods of loaded SWF on init

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a Flash AIR app that loads other SWFs into itself. The problem is that the loaded SWFs can also have code that can mess with my parent that loads them.

I've limited myself to only remove frame-scripts via addFrameScript(frame, null) that I want to call just as my child SWF loads and the document class constructor is being used, but before the main timeline (and all the frame scripts) is loaded.

Is there a way to

- Disable all action script of a loaded movie?

or

- Call some method before scripts on the timeline of the child SWF are executed?

**EDIT**: I load my SWF like this:

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true; // Cannot import a SWF file when LoaderContext.allowCodeImport is false.

var l:Loader = new Loader();
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSWFLoaded);
l.loadBytes(loadingFile.data, loaderContext);
```

The bytes are loaded with a File object, then the Loader loads the SWF from these bytes.

Comment: Do you mean you want to only use parent swf's class definitions and cover the loaded swf's?

Comment: Load the SWF's in a different context: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html

Comment: @Marijn, that should go in as an answer.

Comment: my bad, will add it as answer. thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

Load the SWF's in a different context: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html

Comment: I tried that before posting the question and basically in AIR you have to set allowCodeImport to true if you with to load other SWFs. If that's not the point I would much appreciate if you'd point me in the right direction.